# php - Calling a jquery dialog box in a div loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How do i call a jquery dialog box from a div in a loop?

See for instance, clicking the `<p>` will show up the profile of selected database user.

Ex:

```
<div id="db-users">

   <div id="user-info1"> //db userinfo 1
     <p>ID#001 John Smith</p>
     <div id="dialog-box">Profile of John Smith</div>
   </div>

   <div id="user-info2"> //db userinfo 2
      <p>ID#002 John Doe</p>
      <div id="dialog-box">Profile of John Doe</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

EDIT: By the way , here is what i have done so far

```
$('p').click(function() {
        $('#dialog-box').dialog({

       modal: true,
       width:560,
       height: 500,
       draggable: false,
       buttons: {
        Close: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
       }
    });
});
```

Only one dialog box is showing up, only for John Smith. I don't have the idea to come up the desired output. Any help would much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT 2: I added IDs to all div, to identify each div. Now, using jquery, how to implement q dialog box to show up the info when Name is clicked?

Comment: This is just the markup. What have you tried in terms of implementing the jQuery dialog box?

Comment: @Josh : Hi sir, I made an update to my post, please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the IDs from the HTML except for the `db-users`.

The classes aren't really required either, but you can leave them in if you're using them for styling.

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="db-users">
    <div> <!-- db userinfo 1 -->
        <p>ID#001 John Smith</p>
        <div>Profile of John Smith</div>
    </div>

    <div> <!-- db userinfo 2 -->
        <p>ID#002 John Doe</p>
        <div>Profile of John Doe</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery (assuming 1.7):

```
$('#db-users p').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next('div').dialog({
        ... your dialog options ...
    });
});
```

Comment: THanks sir, but what if , I have more divs after the p tag?

Comment: Do you want those other `div`s shown?  If not, then it is fine as it is.  If so, then change `$(this).next('div')` to `$(this).siblings('div')`

Comment: Sir, I added IDs on divs, how will call the dialog by by it' ID number?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  This method is concise and does what you need.  To call each div by an ID, you'd have to get that ID somehow and tack it into your selector for the `.dialog( )` call.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same id for boths div, id are uniques, maybe you should use a class for the dialog boxes like this:

```
$('.user-info').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.dialog-box').dialog({
        modal: true,
        width:560,
        height: 500,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            Close: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="db-users">
    <div class="user-info"> //db userinfo 1
        <p>ID#001 John Smith</p>
        <div class="dialog-box">Profile of John Smith</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user-info"> //db userinfo 2
        <p>ID#002 John Doe</p>
        <div class="dialog-box">Profile of John Doe</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You still have duplicate ID names in your HTML

Comment: Thanks sir, I put IDs on each div. Can I call a dialog box by ID ?

Comment: You really need to have an ID ? and thanks @Benjam to correct me